# How to configure OpenMQ to not store all in-flight messages in memory?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, openmq

I've load testing different JMS implementations for our notification service.
No one of ActiveMQ, HornetQ and OpenMQ behave as expected (issues with reliability and message prioritization). But as now I've best results with OpenMQ. Expect two issues that's probably just missconfiguration (I hope). One with JDBC storage

**Test scenario:**

2 producers with one queue send messages with different priority. 1 consumer consuming from queue with constant speed that is slightly lower than producers produce. OpenMQ is running standalone and uses PostgreSQL as persistence storage. All messages are sended and consumed from Apache Camel route and it's all persistent.

**Issues:**

1. After about 50000 messages I see warnings and errors in OpenMQ log about low memory (default cinfiguration with 256Mb Heap size). Producing is throutled by broker and after some time broker stop dispatching at all. Broker JVM memory usage is on maximum.

**How I must configure broker to achieve that goal:**

- Broker do not depend on queue size (up to 1 000 000 msgs) and on memory limit. Performance is not issue - only reliability.

**Thats possible?**

Answer (score 0):

I can not help with OpenMQ but perhaps with Camel and ActiveMQ. What issues do you face with ActiveMQ? Can you post your camel route and eventually spring context and the activemq config?

Comment: Thanx for reply!
[http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-with-message-prioritization-and-JDBC-td4199639.html]

Comment: There no answer at all. In ActiveMQ Jira I've see same bugs.

+ recently, in preprod env I've https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1063 but with MS SQL Server.
We've not any stable configuration of ActiveMQ with message prioritization. Workaround with multiple consumers with selectors also does'nt work (the same issues as with one consumer).
All described bugs is in Jira 100% reproducible and ignored or incorrectly marked as closed with ActiveMQ developers :(

Comment: Wait for ActiveMQ 5.6.0 which has many bug fixes and improvements.

Comment: Unfortunaly we must provide working software now...
We are successfully integrate OpenMQ in Servicemix 4 as main broker. As now we worked of patching Aries Transaction implementation (for XA), that not configurable at all (JIRA bug raised already). I think, OSS integration stack from Apache is too buggy for serios production deployments. Not only ActiveMQ.
But Camel is rock! Thank you Claus for hard work on it.